# Execute code only after a non-thenable, asynchronous function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, deferred

I want to execute my code only after `flexslider()` function completes. The problem is that `flexslider()` does not return a promise or other thenable.

So I applied this nasty workaround with `setTimeout` that I want to get rid of. How can I refactor this and execute my code only after `flexslider` is initialized?

```
(function($) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $navBar = $('.primary-nav');
        var navbarPosition = $navBar.offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

            if (scrollPosition >= navbarPosition) {
                $navBar.addClass('navbar-fixed');
            } else {
                $navBar.removeClass('navbar-fixed');
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: how about `$(whatever).flexslider(whatever).promise()` - is that a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `start:`

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false,
  start: function(){
    // do something....
  }
});
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties)

Comment: That works, thanks. I didn't go through the documentation carefully enough. Just a hypothetical question. Would there be a way to achieve the same if `flexslider()` did not provide any callback functionality at all?